# How to sort Wrapper list?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a wrapper class which contains a list of sobjects, i want to have th sorting on the fields of these objects in the wrapper list:
The apex code is as follows:

```
Class jobsWrapper {
    public JobSuite__Job__c job { get; set; }
    public JobSuite__Job_Task__c jobTasks { get; set; }

    public JobsWrapper(JobSuite__Job__c objjobs, JobSuite__Job_Task__c objjobTasks) {
        // if(jobTasks== NULL){jobTasks = new List<Job_Task__c>();}
        job = objjobs;
        jobTasks = objjobTasks; 
    }

    public JobsWrapper() {
        if(jobTasks== NULL) {
            jobTasks = new JobSuite__Job_Task__c();
        }

        if(job == NULL) {
            job = new JobSuite__Job__c();
        }        
    }
}
```

I want to allow sorting the wrapper list by the fields in the job - like client, jobname, jobnumber etc and fields from the task object as taskname, reviseddue dateetc.

How can I do this?
Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40):

Apex provides a [sort method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm) on the List class for sorting. For objects such as this however, you must implement the [Comparable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm) interface. Note the Salesforce doc samples indicate you need to make your class 'global' scope, this is no longer true.

```
public class jobsWrapper implements Comparable
{
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) 
    {
        jobsWrapper jobsWrapper = (jobsWrapper) compareTo;
        if (job.Name == jobsWrapper.job.Name) return 0;
        if (job.Name > jobsWrapper.job.Name) return 1;
        return -1;        
    }
}
```

Then once you put your objects into a list you can use the sort method.

```
List<jobsWrapper> jobs = new List<jobsWrapper>();
// Add things to the list ...
jobs.sort();
```

Comment: +1 .I liked this answer lot .Thanks Andrew .As a developer i frequently come here to see code snippets and these snippets are valuable for quick reference

Comment: Hi Andrew, i tried my example using your same approach given above but sorting does not happen and compareTo method never called. Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 12):

Ok i was a little bit too slow, but here is my idea (a little bit more specific):
You could use the [Comparable interface](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm) and create a dynamic compareTo method

```
public Class OuterClass {
   public static String sortBy {get; set;}
   ...
   Class jobsWrapper implements Comparable{
      ...
      public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
         jobsWrapper compareTo = (jobsWrapper)compareTo;
         if (outerClass.sortBy.equals('clientAsc')){
            return job.client__c.compareTo(compareTo.job.client__c);       
         } else if (outerClass.sortBy.equals('clientDesc')) {
            return job.client__c.compareTo(compareTo.job.client__c) * (-1);       
         } else if (outerClass.sortBy.equals('SomeDateAsc')) {
            if (job.date.isSameDay(compareTo.job.date)) return 0;
            if (job.date.daysBetween(compareTo.job.date) > 0) return 1;
            return -1; 
         } else {
            ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So you have to set the static sortBy property and then you can simply use the list.sort() method:

```
OuterClass.sortBy='client';
jobWrapperList.sort();
```

Comment: Thanks all for the quick reply,
I used the comparable inteface and was able to sort the list in the ascending order, but i also want to sort the columns in the descending order, as well i want to sort the list on the date fields too.
Please reply,
Thanks in advance,
Sushma

Comment: I added some more examples. Alternatively you could add another static variable for ascending or descending.

Comment: Nice and tidy :) Pity it has to be a standalone class (inner classes can't have static members if I recall correctly). But needs some null checks or rewrite to use `==` instead of `equals()` and `-` instead of `daysBetween()` or there will be many annoying null pointer exceptions :) And drop the "global" - they recently fixed it so it can be a normal "public" class & method, I don't expose too much stuff as global if I don't have to, gives nasty ideas to integrators who consume your WSDL ;)

Comment: @Frederik as per Andrew comment, if static is not allowed means, what would be the alternative approach?

Comment: Put the static variable out of the inner class to the outer class. I edited the code a little bit to make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Andrew's excellent example above, you can simplify it a bit more if you're comparing based on a String type. For instance, you can invoke the "native" String compareTo method like below:

```
public class jobsWrapper implements Comparable {
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo){
        jobsWrapper jobsWrapper = (jobsWrapper) compareTo;
        String thisName = (jobs == null || String.isEmpty(jobs.Name) ? '' : jobs.Name);
        String thatName = (jobsWrapper == null || jobsWrapper.job == null || String.isEmpty(jobsWrapper.job.Name) ? '' : jobsWrapper.job.Name);
        return thisName.compareTo(thatName);
    } 
}
```

Note: I added some null checking as well in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper list Sorting.

For Example this wrapper list  ( List allcWraplist = new List())
                          Now we sort the above wrapper list

```
                        // Add Method for Wrapper Sorting where you define wrapper class attibute
                        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo)
                        {
                            AllocationWrapper compareToGoal = (AllocationWrapper)compareTo;

                            if(type < compareToGoal.type)
                            return 1;
                            else if (type < compareToGoal.type)
                            return -1;
                            else
                            return 0;
                        }

                      Now we Use for Sorting 
                      allcWraplist.sort(); //Implement compareTo for Wrapper List Sorting
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *@AndrewFawcett* and *@Frederik*, I added some useful examples too for you and or future devs

#### Example

---

Suppose that you have a VF Page and also a Custom Controller, and you want to sort your own 'viewModel' objects List

**The Apex Controller Class**

```
public with sharing class YourObjGridListController {
    public static String sortBy {get; set;}

    public List<MyWrapperClass> viewModel {get;set;}
    public class MyWrapperClass implements Comparable{

        ChildObj__c childObj {get;set;}
    
        public Integer compareTo(Object obj) {
            MyWrapperClass  compareTo = (MyWrapperClass )obj; 
            //String
            if (YourObjGridListController.sortBy.equals('email')){
                if (childObj.Email__c == compareTo.childObj.Email__c) return 0;
                if (childObj.Email__c > compareTo.childObj.Email__c) return 1;
                return -1;       
            }  
            //Date
            else if (YourObjGridListController.sortBy.equals('someDate')){
                if (childObj.SomeDate == compareTo.childObj.SomeDate) return 0;
                if (childObj.SomeDate> compareTo.childObj.SomeDate) return 1;
                return -1;       
            } 
            //Boolean
            else if (YourObjGridListController.sortBy.equals('isEnabled')){
                if (childObj.isEnabled == compareTo.childObj.isEnabled) return 0;
                if (childObj.isEnabled && !compareTo.childObj.isEnabled) return 1;
                return -1;       
            } 
            //and so...
        }
    }

    public System.PageReference sort(){
        System.debug(sortBy);
        this.model.sort();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**The Visual Force Page**

```
<th class="" scope="col">
    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Email">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Email">
            <apex:param value="email" name="sortBy" assignTo="{!sortBy}"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
    </div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Some Date">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Some Date">
            <apex:param value="someDate" name="sortBy" assignTo="{!sortBy}"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
    </div>
</th>
<th class="" scope="col">
    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Is Enabled">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!sort}" value="Is Enabled">
            <apex:param value="isEnabled" name="sortBy" assignTo="{!sortBy}"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
    </div>
</th>
```