# Sort List of SObject in Wrapper Class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, comparable

I have Wrapper class which contains List of Map.
After performing some operations that List values order gets changed.

```
public class TeacherAvailabilityWrapper{
    public List<Session__c> session{get;set;}
    public Set<Date> dateOnCalender{get;set;}
    public Map<Date,List<Session__c>> dateSession{set;get;}
    public Map<String,List<Session__c>> sessionByDay{set;get;}


    public Integer srno{get;set;}
    public String Teacher{get;set;}
    public Id IdTeacher{get;set;}
    public TeacherAvailabilityWrapper(){
       session = new List<Session__c>();
    }
}
```

Now I want to sort **List** of **dateSession**. Based on Start_time__c (DateTime)field in session.

How to achieve it using Comparable interface?

applied **PPS** logic of @Keith C
[image]

I added following code

```
for(TeacherAvailabilityWrapper twrap: listTeacherAvailWrap){
            for(Date twDt: twrap.dateSession.KeySet()){
                Session__c[] sessions = twrap.dateSession.get(d);
                SessionWrapper[] wrappers = new SessionWrapper[] {};
                for (Session__c s : sessions) wrappers.add(new SessionWrapper(s));
                wrappers.sort();
                sessions.clear();
                for (SessionWrapper w : wrappers) sessions.add(w.sob);
            }
            System.debug('sessionByDay--> '+ twrap.sessionByDay);
        }
```

Comment: have you tried with [comparable Interface](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/how-to-sort-wrapper-list?rq=1) ?

Comment: I am not getting from where to start for comparable interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The confusion is that your class is not really what is termed a wrapper in the Apex community as a wrapper usually decorates a single object instance not a collection. Best drop that suffix from your class.

A wrapper that allows easy sorting (see [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm)) by the field you specify (assuming the field is never null) would look like this:

```
public class SessionWrapper implements Comparable {
    public Session__c sob;
    public SessionWrapper(Session__c sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        SessionWrapper that = (SessionWrapper) o;
        if (this.sob.Start_time__c < that.sob.Start_time__c) return -1;
        else if (this.sob.Start_time__c > that.sob.Start_time__c) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

and if you then have a list of these objects you can sort like this:

```
List<Sessionrapper> sessions = ...;
sessions.sort();
```

But you would need to re-design your class to fit this into your logic.

**PS**

This would do the sort any time the `session` field is referenced if you think about when the session objects are added and accessed and only do the sort when needed you would avoid wasted compution:

```
public List<Session__c> session {
    get {
        if (session != null) {
            SessionWrapper[] wrappers = new SessionWrapper[] {};
            for (Session__c s : session) wrappers.add(new SessionWrapper(s));
            wrappers.sort();
            session.clear();
            for (SessionWrapper w : wrappers) session.add(w.sob);
       }
       return session;
   }
    set;
}
```

**PPS**

The lists in your code are separate so sorting one list does not sort any of the other lists. So if you need you `dateSession` lists sorting, just before you display them in your page run this code:

```
for (Date d : dateSession.keySet()) {
    Session__c[] sessions = dateSession.get(d);
    SessionWrapper[] wrappers = new SessionWrapper[] {};
    for (Session__c s : sessions) wrappers.add(new SessionWrapper(s));
    wrappers.sort();
    sessions.clear();
    for (SessionWrapper w : wrappers) sessions.add(w.sob);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith for the reply I am updating the wrapper class. Actually I had neglected some of the variables from it.

Comment: I want to sort list inside the wrapper class

Comment: @SFDCshaikh See the PS.

Comment: How it will sort y Start_time__c  field?

Comment: @SFDCshaikh By comparing those fields in the `compareTo` method that gets called when the list `sort` method is called.

Comment: The issue was with DateTime Field. So I created formula field with type Text And Used @Keith's solution. Thankss it worked.......!